# Issue with mobile.loading and timing - JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to show the loading animation during a function call that takes some time. The function call is searching a large array that is already loaded. After the search, matching items are inserted into a table. The table is cleared prior to starting the search.

The problem is the animation only displays during the brief moment when the page updates.

Here is my code:

```
var interval = setInterval(function ()
{
   $.mobile.loading('show');
   clearInterval(interval);
}, 1);

DoSearch(term, function ()
{
   var interval = setInterval(function ()
   {
      $.mobile.loading('hide');
      clearInterval(interval);
   }, 1000);
});

//The search function looks like this (detail omitted for brevity):
function DoSearch(term)
{
    $("table#tableICD tbody").html('');

    // also tried:
    /*$("table#tableICD tbody")
    .html('')
    .table()
    .closest("table#tableICD")
    .table("refresh")
    .trigger("create");*/

    var tr = '';

    $.each(codes, function (key, value)
    {
       // determine which items match and add them as table rows to 'tr'
    });


    $("table#tableICD tbody")
       .append(tr)
       .closest("table#tableICD")
       .table("refresh")
       .trigger("create");

    callback();
}
```

The search works properly and adds the rows to the table. I have two unexpected behaviors:

1. The table does not clear until the search is complete. I have tried adding .table("refresh").trigger("create") to the line where I set the tbody html to an empty string. This does not help. (see commented line in the code)
2. As I mentioned, the animation displays briefly while the screen is refreshing. (Notice I set the interval to 1000 in the second setInterval function just so I could even see it.)

The suggestions I have read so far are to use setInterval instead of straight calling $.mobile.loading, which I have done and placing the search in a function and using a callback, which I have also done.

Any ideas?

Comment: A little more information, I can check the visibility of the div with class .ui-loader and see that jquery is setting the visibility of the loader at the correct time. The problem is the screen is not refreshing until all the work is done. At this point I have not figured out how to force a re-flow. For something you are supposed to avoid, you'd think it would be easier to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a few suggestions; they will probably not solve all your issues but they may help you found a solution.

1. jQuery Mobile is buggy, and for some features, we will never know were they intended to work like that or are they just plain bugs
2. You can call $.mobile.loading('show') on its own only in pageshow jQuery Mobile event. In any other case, you need to do it in interval or timeout.
3. It is better to do it in timeout, mostly because you are using less code. Here an example I made several years ago: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Zr7Gf/

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){     
       setTimeout(function(){
           $.mobile.loading('show');
       },1);    
   });

   $(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){
       // You do not need timeout for pageshow. I'm using it so you can see loader is actualy working
       setTimeout(function(){
           $.mobile.loading('hide');
       },300);      
   });
   ```
4. It's difficult to enhance any jQuery Markup in real time after a page was loaded. So my advice is to first generate new table content, then clean it, and then update markup using **.table("refresh")**.
5. Do table refresh only once, never do it several times in the row. It is very resourced heavy method and it will last a very long time if you run it for every row
6. If you are searching on keypress in the input box then showing it in the table; that is the least efficient method in jQuery Mobile. jQM is that slow, it is much better to use listview component which is least resource extensive.